# Flatten a graph without a for loop

Tags: javascript, generator, eslint

I've made this function,

```
function* flattenErrorSchema(errorSchema, path = '') {
  if (errorSchema) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line es/no-for-of-loops
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(errorSchema)) {
      if (key === '__errors') {
        yield* value.map((error) => `${path} : "${error}"`);
      } else {
        yield* flattenErrorSchema(value, `${path}${path ? ' -> ' : ''}${key}`);
      }
    }
  }

  return;
}
```

It walks an [RJSF `errorSchema` prop](https://react-jsonschema-form.readthedocs.io/en/v1.8.1/advanced-customization/#field-props) that could look something like this,

```
{
  data: {
    propA: {
      __errors: ['This is not right'],
    },
    propB: {
      __errors: ['Also wrong', 'This is bad'],
    },
  },
}
```

and yields a sequence of messages that look like this,

```
[
  'data -> propA : "This is not right"',
  'data -> propB : "Also wrong"',
  'data -> propB : "This is bad"',
]
```

This all works well but, as you can see, I've had to disable an ESLint rule,

```
// eslint-disable-next-line es/no-for-of-loops
```

Is there a way to achieve the same functionality, without using a for-of loop, that avoids allocations and "uglier", "smellier" code?

Comment: why would you disable `for of` loops?

Comment: @georg, that is a reasonable question that I have asked myself. If the answer to this question is, "No, there is no better way to do this", then perhaps that rule will be relaxed.

Comment: From my understanding, the purpose of this rule is to warn you about ES6 stuff if you target an older platform. If this is not the case, there's no need for this.

Comment: @georg or, presumably, if your code is transpiled, the rule is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `for..of` you always can use a normal `for` and you will have the same result.

```js
function* flattenErrorSchema(errorSchema, path = "") {
  if (errorSchema) {
    const entries = Object.entries(errorSchema);
    for (let i = 0; i < entries.length; ++i) {
      const [key,value] = entries[i];
      if (key === "__errors") {
        yield* value.map((error) => `${path} : "${error}"`);
      } else {
        yield* flattenErrorSchema(value, `${path}${path ? " -> " : ""}${key}`);
      }
    }
  }

  return;
}
```